# What is the correct way of parsing this json? Using ArduinoJson

Tags: c++, json, arduino

I can't get the correct way to parse this JSON using ArduinoJson library

Here is the resulting json I need to parse.

```
{
"Error": false,
"Message": "Success",
"Sensor": [
    {
        "id": 10,
        "mac_address": "aabbccddeeff",
        "status": "ON"
    }
  ]
}
```

May target value to get is the value of "status"

I tried to get some value and println it, but I got nothing?

Codes I tried so far.

```
  StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer;
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(path);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  String payload = http.getString();
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(payload);
  String state = root["Sensor"];
  Serial.println(payload);
  Serial.println(state);    //Print request response payload
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon searching, I found that the author create an assistant to convert your defined json string.
You can find it here
https://bblanchon.github.io/ArduinoJson/assistant/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`Sensor` is a list with a single object that has your desired property `status`.

```
String state = root["Sensor"][0]["status"];
```